# Unable to open a file using .fileImporter on actual device

Tags: swiftui

This use to work when deployed on a real device when I was testing iOS 14 beta, but now in production it only works on the emulator. Did something change in IOS 14? I received the following error:

FilePickerTest[15486:5885508] [AXRuntimeCommon] Unknown client: FilePickerTest

The file “16010282771_20190702_23_38.csv” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it.

Is there a setting I need to add to give my app permission to access the file?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var openFile = false
    @StateObject var doc = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Tap to pick a csv file")
                .padding()
                .onTapGesture(perform: {
                    openFile.toggle()
                })
        }
        .fileImporter(isPresented: $openFile, allowedContentTypes: [.commaSeparatedText]) { (res) in
            do {
                let fileUrl = try res.get()
                print(fileUrl)
                doc.viewFile(fileUrl: fileUrl)
            } catch {
                print("Error reading file")
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    var readString = ""
    func viewFile(fileUrl: URL) {
        do {
            readString = try String(contentsOf: fileUrl)
        } catch {
            print("Error reading file")
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        
        print("File contents: \(readString)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Found one possible solution, which works: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/forums/swiftui/looking-for-help-how-to-select-and-open-an-existing-data-file-with-a-document-browser/3953

Answer (score 7):

add fileUrl.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
before
doc.viewFile(fileUrl: fileUrl)

Comment: That works perfectly!

Comment: Important: Don't forget to call `stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()` when you're done with the file. See more here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl/1413736-stopaccessingsecurityscopedresou

Comment: only use stop if start returned true!