# Convert PDF To Base64 in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, base64

I am **fetching PDF** data. It provides me **URL**, and when I am converting it to **base64**. This is what I am getting:

> The file “file.pdf” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it.

I am not getting why is it giving this. This is how I am getting the **pdf file** url:

```
 @State var openPDF = false
 @State var fileName = ""
 @State var pdfFile : URL?

  var body: some View {

   Button {
        self.openPDF.toggle()
    }, label {
         
          Text("Add Attachment")
     }.fileImporter(isPresented: $vm.openPDF, allowedContentTypes: [.pdf]) { result in
                    
            do {

                let fileURL = try result.get()
                print(fileURL)

                self.fileName = fileURL.lastPathComponent

                self.pdfFile = fileURL
              } catch {
                    print("error getting documents")
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                   }
             }
}
```

An this is how I am converting it to **base64**:

```
    do {
            
        let filePath = pdfFile
        let fileData = try Data.init(contentsOf: filePath!)
        let fileStream:String = fileData.base64EncodedString()
        print(fileStream)
    } catch {
        print("error")
        print(error.localizedDescription)
   }
```

In this **do-catch**, it is giving the error that "this file could not be opened because you don't have permission.

Comment: Where is that file located? What platform are you targeting, iOS, macOS?

Comment: @DávidPásztor I have Iphone 13 pro max. I am testing on it

Comment: What is the URL though? Is the file located in your app Bundle? Or application directory? Are you aware of sandboxing rules for iOS apps?

Comment: @DávidPásztor the url is the application directory:  `file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/ECF8B2D3-0091-4A29-96C6-3554939C8061/File%20Provider%20Storage/ML%20Branch%20Test%20-%20Sheet1%20(1).pdf` . And I am not aware of sandboxing rules

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64992001/unable-to-open-a-file-using-fileimporter-on-actual-device ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this to convert PDF to Base64 String:

```
fileapp.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() {
            defer {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    fileapp.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
                }
            }
            
            do {
                
                let fileData = try Data.init(contentsOf: fileapp)
                let fileStream:String = fileData.base64EncodedString()
                print(fileStream)
                base64PDF = fileStream
            } catch {
                print("error")
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

My Code for converting PDF to Base64String
Here fileName is State variable and base64PDF is also a State variable

I have used If condition before fileurl because it is giving error

```
    Text(fileName)
        .fileImporter(isPresented: $isImporting, allowedContentTypes: [.pdf]) { result in
            do{
                let fileUrl = try result.get()
                self.fileName = fileUrl.lastPathComponent
                print(fileUrl)
                
                if fileUrl.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() {
                    defer {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            fileUrl.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
                        }
                    }
                    
                    do {
                        
                        let fileData = try Data.init(contentsOf: fileUrl)
                        let fileStream:String = fileData.base64EncodedString()
                        print(fileStream)
                        base64PDF = fileStream
                        print(base64PDF)
                        
                    } catch {
                        print("error")
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
                
            }catch{
                print("Error reading docs")
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. A good answer explains what was wrong with the OP's code and explains how the answer fixes the issue. Please update your answer with relevant details. Also explain how your answer is different from the other existing answer.